# Group array of objects with object keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, data-structures

What is the best way to Group an array of objects according to the keys in vanilla javascript, lets say I have 10000 records, this is the sample object

```
[
 {
  company: "TATA",
  car: "TATA Indica",
  color: "Blue"
 },
 {
  company: "TATA",
  car: "TATA Indica",
  color: "Black"
 },
 {
  company: "TATA",
  car: "Safari",
  color: "Blue"
 },
 {
   "company": "Suzuki",
    car: "",
    color: ""
 }
]
```

and the expected output is

```
{
   "company": ["TATA", "Suzuki"],
   "car": ["TATA Indica", "Safari"],
   "color": ["Blue", "Black"]
}
```

Comment: Does the order important here for end result arrays like `company`, `car`, or `color`?

Comment: You should have provided your attempt at it

Comment: You have accepted the slowest version. https://jsben.ch/kLhTZ

Comment: pilchard have now the fastest solution! https://jsben.ch/4KKgm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Set` to store the unique values for each key and convert them back to array later

```js
const data = [
  {
    company: "TATA",
    car: "TATA Indica",
    color: "Blue",
  },
  {
    company: "TATA",
    car: "TATA Indica",
    color: "Black",
  },
  {
    company: "TATA",
    car: "Safari",
    color: "Blue",
  },
  {
    company: "Suzuki",
    car: "",
    color: "",
  },
]

let res = data.reduce((acc, el) => {
  for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(el)) {
    if (!value) continue

    if (key in acc) {
      const set = new Set(acc[key])
      set.add(value)
      acc[key] = Array.from(set)
    } else {
      acc[key] = [value]
    }
  }

  return acc
}, {})

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Well, this is the slowest version.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) here, and to optimize it you can use [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) here.

```js
const arr = [{
    company: "TATA",
    car: "TATA Indica",
    color: "Blue",
  },
  {
    company: "TATA",
    car: "TATA Indica",
    color: "Black",
  },
  {
    company: "TATA",
    car: "Safari",
    color: "Blue",
  },
  {
    company: "Suzuki",
    car: "",
    color: "",
  },
];

const result = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  Object.keys(curr).forEach((k) => {
    if (curr[k]) {
      if (!acc[k]) acc[k] = new Set();
      else acc[k].add(curr[k]);
    }
  });
  return acc;
}, {});

Object.keys(result).forEach((k) => (result[k] = [...result[k]]));
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

For primitive values you can easily use the combination of [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) and [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map).
You use `Map` for the keys and `Set` for the values.

```js
const companies = ["TATA", "Suzuki", "Škoda", ""];
const cars = ["TATA Indica", "Safari", "Fabia", ""];
const colors = ["Blue", "Black", "Red", "Yellow", ""]
const arr = Array.from({length: 1000}, (v, i) => ({
  company: companies[i % companies.length],
  car: cars[i % cars.length],
  color: colors[i % colors.length]
}));

console.time('Operation');
const map = new Map();
for(let item of arr) {
  for(let key of Object.keys(item)){
    let keySet = map.get(key);
    if(!keySet){
      keySet = new Set();
      map.set(key, keySet);
    }
    const value = item[key];
    if(value !== '') {
      keySet.add(item[key]);
    }
  }
}
const result = {};
for(let key of map.keys()) {
  result[key] = Array.from(map.get(key));
}
console.timeEnd('Operation');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are using data that has a stable shape throughout. In this case you can declare the shape of the result object in advance, and then simply accumulate the data into it only checking for non-empty values. Here using [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and [Set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set) for the accumulation and then mapping it to the final result object.

```js
const data = [{ company: 'TATA', car: 'TATA Indica', color: 'Blue' }, { company: 'TATA', car: 'TATA Indica', color: 'Black' }, { company: 'TATA', car: 'Safari', color: 'Blue' }, { company: 'Suzuki', car: '', color: '' },];

const map = new Map(Object.keys(data[0]).map((k) => [k, new Set()]));

for (const d of data) {
  for (const k of map.keys()) {
    if (d[k] !== '') {
      map.get(k).add(d[k]);
    }
  }
}

const result = {};
for (const k of map.keys()) {
  result[k] = Array.from(map.get(k));
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Curiously, what seems like the most naive implementation actually proves fairly performant (per [@Totati's benchmark](https://jsben.ch/4KKgm)). Serial `map().filter()` calls.

```js
const data = [{ company: 'TATA', car: 'TATA Indica', color: 'Blue' }, { company: 'TATA', car: 'TATA Indica', color: 'Black' }, { company: 'TATA', car: 'Safari', color: 'Blue' }, { company: 'Suzuki', car: '', color: '' },];

const result = {};

for (const k of Object.keys(data[0])) {
  result[k] = Array.from(
    new Set(data.map(({ [k]: key }) => key).filter((n) => n !== ''))
  );
}

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thanks @Totati (though you left my real answer off ;) [https://jsben.ch/4KKgm](https://jsben.ch/4KKgm))